# Was Flashpoint timeline bad enough to be reset?

Tags: plot-explanation, arrowverse, the-flash

I'm not sure I understand the reason for Barry to reset the Flashpoint timeline in *The Flash season 3* episode 1. There were several negative changes in Flashpoint:

1. Barry was losing his memory;
2. Joe West became a drinker;
3. Caitlin Snow and Cisco Ramon had different jobs;
4. Wally West got badly wounded by the Rival.

But were they enough for Barry to let his parents be killed again? If so, then why?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's subjective. Flashpoint is not as bad as it was in comics, but a lot of things were changed especially related to Barry Allen. His friends are not as much help, as they were in pre-flashpoint to deal with metahuman issues. Wally West was not healing and might die.

So was Flashpoint timeline bad enough to be reset?

For Barry Allen yes, that's why he reverse it. In his own words:

> **Barry:** I thought I could just make things better, but everyone has been paying for my happiness. Will you help me?
>
> **Iris:** Do what?
>
> **Barry:** Make things right.